# Correct way to set up DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hey I am trying to pull an image from a private artifactory repository .My gitlab-ci.yml file looks like below :

```
stages:
  - run_script

run_script:
  image : artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest
  stage: 
    run_script
  script:
    - docker pull aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo.artifactory.bayer.com/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest
```

I have set up DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG like below which I have added as CI Variable:

```
{
        "auths": { 
                "aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo.artifactory.****.com": {  
                        "auth": "dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ3535aCBzcGFjZXMgaW4gaXQK"  
               }  
        }  
}
```

The auth part I have gotten from :

`echo "username:password with spaces in it" | base64` through Git BASH .

I am getting below error :

```
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "if-not-present": Error response from daemon: unauthorized (manager.go:205:0s)
ERROR: Preparation failed: failed to pull image "artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest" with specified policies [if-not-present]: Error response from daemon: unauthorized (manager.go:205:0s)
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): failed to pull image "artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest" with specified policies [if-not-present]: Error response from daemon: unauthorized (manager.go:205:0s)
```

My question is whats the right way to configure DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG ? And does this method work to pull private image ?

Answer (score 2):

My guess will be that there is problem with new line within encoded stream or username/password have typos.

try to use right method from gitlab.com:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determine-your-docker_auth_config-data

I am using same authentication way and it works, also try to check if locally from docker login you are able to download that image, sometimes restrictions on level of access are not working correctly

Answer (score 0):

It's `aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo.artifactory` inside the auths file and in a different way in `image`: `artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory`

It should be aligned following the pattern:

```
image: registry.example.com:5000/namespace/image:tag
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first place you are using:

```
image : artifactory.bayer.com/artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest
```

to execute the command:

```
docker pull aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo.artifactory.bayer.com/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest
```

*GitLab* tries to fetch the image `artifactory/aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo:latest` from the private repository `artifactory.bayer.com`.

The error you are getting is related to this first image fetch.

Observing your `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`, and assuming that you defined it as a variable in admin/project *CI/CD Variables*, then you need also to specify authentication for the private repository **artifactory.bayer.com**.

*GitLab Runner* uses variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` to fetch the image that run the step, and since the image that runs the step is in **artifactory.bayer.com** repository, you need to add it also to the variable (that currently only as authentication for repository `aie-docker-dev-mydockerrepo.artifactory.****.com`).